Plotting each row in a pandas DataFrame as a bar with seaborn
Given such a dataframe,
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[2,3],'c':[3,4],'d':[1,2],'code':[1,2]})

a   b   c   d   code
0   1   2   3   1   1
1   2   3   4   2   2

I want to have a barplot with a 2 bars for each column (one for each row...)
this one
sns.barplot(data.iloc[0])

works just fine,

but when i try to doit for 2 columns,
sns.barplot(data,hue='code')

claims:

ValueError: The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form
data: hue


You can set_index on "code", transpose, then plot.bar:
data.set_index('code').T.plot.bar()

Output:

With seaborn, you would first need to melt the data:
sns.barplot(data.melt('code'), x='variable', y='value', hue='code')

Output:

